# Ошибка при использовании Ajax ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, c#

Здравствуйте!
У меня возникла проблема с использовании Ajax ScriptManager. Я его применил в чате. На моем IIS все нормально работает, никаких проблем. Но вот когда я его залил на хостинге, то выходит следующая ошибка:

SCRIPT5022: [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) Ajax client-side framework failed to load
SCRIPT5009: "Sys" не определено

Уже пересмотрел все что можно и ни где толкового рецепта не нашел для решения данной проблемы. 
Может кто либо сталкивался с данной ситуацией.

Вот содержание web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="WebApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <location allowOverride="false">
        <system.web>
          <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
        </system.web>
      </location>
      <appSettings>

        <!-- chat keys -->
        <add key="ChatLoggedInText" value="Только что вошел! "/>
        <add key="CheckTemporaryConversationCount" value="5"/>
        <add key="CheckTemporaryConversationInterval" value="2"/>
        <add key="CheckForNewMessageInterval" value="5"/>
        <add key="CheckForNewConversationInterval" value="10"/>
        <add key="CheckForContactStatusesInterval" value="10"/>
        <add key="InactivityOfflineInterval" value="60"/>

        <add key="domain" value="sudak.schools.in.ua"/>
        <add key="webProxy" value=""/>
        <add key="maxImageWidth" value="3000"/>
        <add key="maxImageHeight" value="3000"/>
        <add key="maxFileSize" value="52428800"/>
        <add key="imageMiniautureMaxSize" value="48"/>
        <add key="PublicationShortContentMaxLength" value="1000"/>
        <add key="maxSessionInActivityDates" value="1"/>
        <add key="maxCommandCacheInActivityDates" value="1"/>
        <add key="SaveInDb" value="N"/>
        <add key="MaxDocumentsPageSize" value="10"/>
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>

      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <!-- 
                Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
                symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
                affects performance, set this value to true only 
                during development.
            -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="51200"/>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <!--
                The <authentication> section enables configuration 
                of the security authentication mode used by 
                ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
            -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Responser.aspx" name="AuthCookie" timeout="10080" />
        </authentication>

        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
        <!--
                The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
                of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

            <customErrors mode="Off">

            </customErrors>
            -->
        <httpHandlers>
          <add verb="*" path="*FileUploadHandler.as" type="WebApp.HttpModules.UploadHandler, WebApp"/>
          <add verb="*" path="*ImageHandler.as" type="WebApp.HttpModules.ImageHandler, WebApp"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="PageCreator" type="WebApp.HttpModules.PageCreator, WebApp"/>
          <add name="DomainDetector" type="WebApp.HttpModules.DomainDetector, WebApp"/>
          <add name="Authenticator" type="WebApp.HttpModules.Authenticator, WebApp"/>
        </httpModules>
        <trace enabled="true" traceMode="SortByTime"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="ru-RU" uiCulture= "ru-RU"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true"/>

      </system.diagnostics>
      <!-- 
            The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
            Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
        -->
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <add name="PageCreator" type="WebApp.HttpModules.PageCreator, WebApp"/>
          <add name="DomainDetector" type="WebApp.HttpModules.DomainDetector, WebApp"/>
          <add name="Authenticator" type="WebApp.HttpModules.Authenticator, WebApp"/>    
        </modules>
        <handlers>
          <add name="FileUpload" verb="*" path="*FileUploadHandler.as" type="WebApp.HttpModules.UploadHandler, WebApp"/>
          <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*ImageHandler.as" type="WebApp.HttpModules.ImageHandler, WebApp"/>

        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,POST,GET"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value=""/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000"/>
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      </system.webServer>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ajaxBinding_1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2048000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
          <endpoint address="*" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Framework.DataContracts.IPageService" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="ajaxBinding_1">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService.PageServiceBehavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
              <webHttp/>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <log4net>
        <logger name="WebLogger">
          <level value="ALL"/>
          <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        </logger>
        <!-- see: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html -->
        <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
          <!-- .resx extension is not served -->
          <file value="Logs\log.txt"/>
          <appendToFile value="true"/>
          <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
          <!-- starts new logfile each day -->
          <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- see: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/index.html for syntax (refer to: log4net.Layout.PatternLayout class) -->
            <conversionPattern value="***Level: %level%n%date{ISO8601}%nAppl.Uptime: %timestamp ms%nLogger: %logger%n%message%nCode version: %property{CodeVersion}%n%property{RewrittenUrl}%n%exception"/>
            <!--conversionPattern value="%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" /-->
          </layout>
        </appender>
      </log4net>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: а что за хостинг? какая версия .net?

Comment: Windows хостинг, .net Framework 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас неправильные настройки в файле Web.config. Настроек в, которых Вы могли допустить ошибку много, так что лучше, если Вы приведёте содержимое файла Web.config.
Если Вы не изменяли его, то можете просто заменить содержимое следующим:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Вот выложил web.config